# contenteditable - pressing Enter how to get the code in a separate line

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

a contenteditable div having this html inside

```
<div class='dg'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

placing cursor at the end of line and pressing Enter gives the following html:

```
<div class='dg'>lorem ipsum</div><div class='dg'><br></div>
```

How to get the same but with an empty line between:

```
<div class='dg'>lorem ipsum</div>

<div class='dg'><br></div>
```

Comment: Why would you want it to do that? This feels like it might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I agree with @DBS, moreover, `contententeditable` element behavior varies depending on the browser, so the only real concern is what the result looks like once rendered not the actual HTML.

Comment: @DBS - simply because a large html structure is more readable

Comment: @provance More readable to who? Conventionally, no one should be seeing the HTML structure of the page. If you have a reason to make that visible to users, then we'll need significantly more context about the problem.

Comment: @DBS - More readable for me. And for me - quite enough reason